# Cómo hacer expresiones regulares para un motor de plantillas?

Tags: php

Estoy empezando a realizar un motor de plantillas simple, y quiero comenzar por tomar los valores que están entre {{}} para luego sustituirlos por el valor que el usuario inserte en otro archivo php, es decir

```
Vista1.php

<html>
  <body>
     <p> {{nombre}} </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ya en otro archivo:

```
$template = new Templates("Vista1");
```

Archivo templates:

```
$view = file_get_contents (" ruta_del_archivo\".$vista."php");
```

Aqui viene lo divertido y en donde no se como implementarlo, que es recorrer dicha vista, viendo que valores tiene e ir sustituyéndolo, un amigo me dijo que el usar str_replace ("{{nombre}}", "roberto") es inseguro, o se usa expresiones regulares o un paseador sintáctico, pero como estoy empezando, no sé nada de eso xD, si me pudieran dar una orientación, consejo, se los agradecería :)

Comment: duda: es un desafio personal tuyo? lo digo porque ya tienes distintos motores de plantillas (twig, blade, ...) que hacen eso mismo y algunas cosas mas...

Comment: @Jakala si, para aprende :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `str_replace('{{nombre}}',$nombre)` sin problemas, pero tendrias que añadir lineas de codigo cada vez que en un archivo del template añadas un nombre de variable diferente.
Por ejemplo, añadir {{x}} en el diseño te obligará a poner `str_replace('{{x}}',$x)` en el archivo PHP que procese el template. Poco practico.

Con [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) y [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) no tendrias que preocuparte de eso.

Para archivos te puede valer esto:

```
 class Templates{
    private string $path;               // ruta donde se almacenan los archivos html
    private array $files=array();       //array asociativo, nombre en clave : archivo

    function __construct(string $path){
        $this->path=$path;
    }

    public function set_file(string $k, string $v){
        $this->filenames[$k]=$v;
        if($v==null){
            $this->files[$k]='';
            unset($this->filenames[$k]);
        }else{
            $f=$this->path.''.$v.'.htm';
            $this->files[$k]=@file_get_contents($f);
            $this->filenames[$k]=$v;
            if(empty($this->files[$k]))
                die('Error grave (el archivo no existe) ya que no encuentra el fichero, por lo que es mejor dejar de ejecutar el script y arreglar el problema.');
        }
    }

    public function set_files($array){
        foreach($array as $k=>$v)
            $this->set_file($k,$v);
    }

    function Parse(string $filename){
        return $this->merge_files($this->files[$filename]);
    }

    function merge_files(string $code){
        $continue=true;
        while($continue){
            $continue=false;
            preg_match_all('#{{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)}}#is',$code,$match);
            foreach($match[1] as $k=>$v)
                if(!empty($this->files[$v])){
                    $continue=true;
                    $code=str_replace($match[0][$k],$this->files[$v],$code);
                }
        }
        $code=preg_replace('#{{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)}}#is','',$code);
        return $code;
    }
 }
 
$template=new Templates('/template/folder/');
$template->set_files(array(
    'HTML_MAIN'                 =>'main',
    'CONTENT'                   =>'fotos',
));
echo $template->parse('HTML_MAIN');exit;
```

`$template=new Templates(PATH.'/admin/template/');` Crea la clase y añade la carpeta donde se encuentran los archivos HTML.
`$template->set_files(array()` Añade los archivos junto con su nombre en clave. En este caso HTML_MAIN tendrá el contenido de `/template/folder/main.htm`.
Por ultimo `$template->parse('HTML_MAIN'); ``  mezclara las filas haciendo de HTML_MAIN la principal.

Para añadir variables seria algo parecido. Primero tendrias que crear la funcion `set_var`o `set_array` y luego otra funcion que procese esos datos.

```
public function set_array(array $array){
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
        $this->data[$k]=$v;
}

function process_vars(string $code){
    return preg_replace('#{{([a-z0-9\.\-_]+?)}}#is','\1',$code);
}
```